# Replace menu permalink/hyperlink with only menu name/slug in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, permalinks

I don't know if i am asking this correctly, but i will try. ***I am doing this for history pushstate purpose.***

**Code** to get menu wihout `ul` and `li`:

```
$topmenu= array(
  'container'       => false,
  'echo'            => false,
  'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
  'depth'           => 0
);

echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $topmenu), '<a>');
```

At the moment, it gives mes only `<a>` tag with `href` as expected.

**For example:**

```
<a href="http://example.com/page1">Page 1</a>
<a href="http://example.com/page2">Page 2</a>
<a href="http://example.com/page3">Page 3</a>
// etc
```

**My question:**

How to disable/hide full permalink/hyperlink in `href` attribute, but keep showing page slug?

**What i need for example:**

```
<a href="/page1"></a>
// etc
```

I tryed to make this work to changing `nav-menu-template.php`, but i failed.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for building a navigation with wp_nav_menu then.
If you just want to get the links of a navigation you've set up in your wordpress backend you need the name, id or slug of the navigation.

You can get the nav_menu_items with

```
$items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'name_of_your_navigation' );
```

Now you need to remove the home_url from each item's url like so

```
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $url = str_replace( home_url(), '', $item->url );
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $url . '</a>';
}
```